# Wrapping Sync code into Async PHP

Tags: php, nonblocking, event-driven, event-driven-design

Let's say I have a blocking long running process that uses SoapClient to connect to a webservice , Is it possible to wrap the normal code into an async way , I'm aware that I can send parallel Soap requests with different libraries , I just want to know is it possible to wrap a blocking process into an async way or not ?

In normal mode a blocking request is sent and waits for response.

In my need multiple blocking request are sent at once, like a job that a multi processing does but in a single process.

Comment: you want to make your client async? or the server? neither makes much sense in PHP, since each request is completely indepedent of each other. you'd have to wait around for the results of the soap call, which by definition is synchronous behavior anyways.

Comment: If you want to make your PHP truly asynchronous, then take a look at something like ReactPHP